# How do I update geckoFx45 to geckofx60?

Tags: browser, updates, geckofx

I have old project it is using geckofx45 with "xulrunner" folder in project.
I tried to replace it and update with geckofx60 from Nuget package but it doesn't have xulrunner folder after completed but instead it added "Firefox" called folder.
So what should I do? I can't even rebuild project now since I didn't make a copy of old project.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try different initiation path?
Instead of

```
Xpcom.Initialize();
```

You could rename your `Firefox` folder to `xulrunner` then use

```
Xpcom.Initialize("xulrunner");
```

Or you keep the `Firefox` folder, and use

```
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
```